# maven: local installed jar not found

Tags: maven

I'm getting this error message:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project com.psgd.template:backend:war:1.0.0: Could not find artifact com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2

I've previously installed this library into local repository using:

```
mvn install:install-file \
 -DgroupId=com.oracle \
 -DartifactId=ojdbc7 \
 -Dversion=12.1.0.2 \
 -Dpackaging=jar \
 -Dfile=ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar \
 -DgeneratePom=true
```

I've look up into my repository:

```
$ ls -Rh ~/.m2/repository/com/oracle/                            
/home/jeusdi/.m2/repository/com/oracle/:
ojdbc7

/home/jeusdi/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc7:
12.1.0.2

/home/jeusdi/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2:
ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar.lastUpdated  ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.pom.lastUpdated
```

So, it's present into local repository.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to run your project after installing this library into your local repository?

Answer (score 0):

Many things can go wrong here.

When you run `mvn install:install-file` you should see the log line in command line: something like : `INFO Installing file ... to full <<PATH_COMES_HERE>>`
So check that path.

If everything works as expected you should be able to see both `pom.xml` and the `jar` in the corresponding folder of your repository, not "lastUpdated" I believe.
I don't see it in the provided snippet...

You can also check permissions as one possible source of issues.

The last thing is checking the actual pom generated by install:install-file. Make sure, the pom is valid and contains the information you've entered.

You can also delete the whole folder from maven repo and re-run `mvn install:install-file` maybe the repo went corrupted for some reason who knows.

Answer (score 0):

The files

```
ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar.lastUpdated  ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.pom.lastUpdated
```

mean that the Maven looked for the pom and did not find it. It is a kind of cache for missing artifacts.

Please delete these two files and try again to install the jar. Then try again to build against it.